# How to use ForeignKey or OneToOneField with Wagtail InlinePanel?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have two models, `Address` and `Subscription`. I would like the `Subscription` model to have a ForeignKey or OneToOne relationship with an `Address`.

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street_address = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        default="",
    )
    ...

class Subscription(models.Model):
    subscriber_address = models.OneToOneField(
        Address,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='related_entity'
    )

    panels = [
        InlinePanel("subscriber_address"),
    ]
```

I would also like for users to be able to edit the address fields when editing a Subscription instance via the Wagtail UI.

However, when trying to create a Subscription with the above configuration, I get the following error:

> 'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'rel'

What is the proper way to render a ForeignKey or OneToOne relationship via the Wagtail InlinePanel?

Comment: It looks like this may be a feature request: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1831

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/ixc/wagtail-instance-selector